# Video editing software for pre-recorded lectures

Tags: audio-video-recording

I am planning to record lectures. My lectures will be slides or notepad with voice-over.

I am interested in a simple to use video editing software. The major things I need to do is

- Cutting out a few seconds
- Freezing the video for a few seconds
- Speeding up or slowing down certain parts
- perhaps do a completely different voice-over

The software should be as portable as possible though I am using Linux for the most part.

Comment: You might find something here: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4680/72855

Comment: Adding subtitles is also useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/) to be a very good video-editing solution on Linux. It is free and open-source, with an active help forum and good documentation. It probably has many more features than you will ever need, but I didn't find the learning curve to be too high as a new user.

Answer (score 0):

Lightweight online video tool: Kapwing (https://www.kapwing.com/)

Education edition:

https://www.kapwing.com/resources/free-kapwing-pro-accounts-for-educators-affected-by-covid-19/

Answer (score 0):

I've been very happy with [OpenShot](https://www.openshot.org/download/). Free and open source, works on Windows, OS X, Linux. I had a problem at one point and the developer community was very helpful in diagnosing and fixing it.